Next Level Number to Restart After Previous Level is Blank
I am using a book file, though this is still a problem even with a normal document that I've tested it with (substituting chapter variables for hard-coded numbers).
I am using InDesign CS 5.5. I haven't tested this problem with CC. If it is still a problem in CC then hopefully my question remains relevant.
Here are the first pages of each of my documents, how I want them to look:
Doc 1: Chapter number set to "automatic"
--------------
Attachment <Chapter Variable>    Para Style: "Numbered List Level 1"
Name of Attachment               Para Style: "Attachment Title"
1.1 Name of Sub-Attachment       Para Style: "Numbered List Level 2"
--------------

Doc 2: Chapter number set to "automatic"
--------------
Attachment <Chapter Variable>    Para Style: "Numbered List Level 1"
Name of Attachment               Para Style: "Attachment Title"
2.1 Name of Sub-Attachment       Para Style: "Numbered List Level 2"
--------------

Doc 3: Chapter number set to "previous document" <--- NOTE
--------------
Attachment <Chapter Variable>    Para Style: "Attachment Number Placeholder" <--- NOTE
Name of Attachment               Para Style: "Attachment Title"
2.2 Name of Sub-Attachment       Para Style: "Numbered List Level 2"
--------------

Doc 4: Chapter number set to "automatic"
--------------
Attachment <Chapter Variable>    Para Style: "Numbered List Level 1"
Name of Attachment               Para Style: "Attachment Title"
3.1 Name of Sub-Attachment       Para Style: "Numbered List Level 2"
--------------

And this is how they are currently looking:
Doc 1: Chapter number set to "automatic"
--------------
Attachment <Chapter Variable>    Para Style: "Numbered List Level 1"
Name of Attachment               Para Style: "Attachment Title"
0.1 Name of Sub-Attachment       Para Style: "Numbered List Level 2"
--------------

Doc 2: Chapter number set to "automatic"
--------------
Attachment <Chapter Variable>    Para Style: "Numbered List Level 1"
Name of Attachment               Para Style: "Attachment Title"
0.2 Name of Sub-Attachment       Para Style: "Numbered List Level 2"
--------------

Doc 3: Chapter number set to "previous document"
--------------
Attachment <Chapter Variable>    Para Style: "Attachment Number Placeholder"
Name of Attachment               Para Style: "Attachment Title"
0.3 Name of Sub-Attachment       Para Style: "Numbered List Level 2"
--------------

Doc 4: Chapter number set to "automatic"
--------------
Attachment <Chapter Variable>    Para Style: "Numbered List Level 1"
Name of Attachment               Para Style: "Attachment Title"
0.4 Name of Sub-Attachment       Para Style: "Numbered List Level 2"
--------------

The only difference between how I want them to look and how they should look is that in the Sub-Attachment the numbering is not correct.
Let me now introduce the numbered list paragraph settings I have in place:
Numbered List level 1:

List Type: Numbers
List: Attachment Titles
Level: 1
Format: 1, 2, 3, 4
Number: `` (blank, empty text, which seems to be the kicker)
Char Style: None
Mode: Continue from Previous

Numbered List level 2 (only showing the differences to level 1 style):

Level: 2
Number: ^1.^# 
Restart Numbers at This Level After: Any Previous Level

Finally, the para style Attachment Number Placeholder is not a numbered list.
Note that in Numbered List Level 2, if I change the Number field from ^1.^#  to ^H.^# , it changes the numbering from:
"^1.^# "                     "^H.^# "
---
Attachment 1                 Attachment 1                               Attachment 1
0.1 Sub-Attachment    to     1.1 Sub-Attachment    What it should be    1.1 Sub-Attachment
---
Attachment 1                 Attachment 1                               Attachment 1
0.2 Sub-Attachment    to     2.2 Sub-Attachment    What it should be    2.1 Sub-Attachment
---
Attachment 1                 Attachment 1                               Attachment 1
0.3 Sub-Attachment    to     2.3 Sub-Attachment    What it should be    2.2 Sub-Attachment
---
Attachment 1                 Attachment 1                               Attachment 1
0.4 Sub-Attachment    to     3.4 Sub-Attachment    What it should be    3.1 Sub-Attachment


As an aside, one might think, "Why don't you set the Number of the
Level 1 para style to Attachment ^#?"
This is because "Attachment [Chapter Number]" repeats itself sometimes (see docs 2 and 3 above).
Also, it is center-aligned and the "Name of Attachment" is also center-aligned and on the next line below, with spacing before. And I found that leaving a center-aligned numbered list without any actual text does not actually center-align it, but sets it off to the left a bit, even if I choose "Number Alignment: Center," until text is added to the line and then it centers properly.
Trust me, I tried this, but couldn't figure out how to make the "Name of Attachment" break to a new line without manually inserting a Forced Line Break and to also have space between the "Attachment ^#" line and the "Name of Attachment" line.

Any ideas how I can take it from what it looks like right now to what I need it to look like?
Thank you.
